# How to completely delete overlapping polygons with one shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, intersection, overlapping-features

I can't figure out a method or find a tool that would completely delete (or disregard) just the overlapping polygons (red) that intersect with the Puerto Rico polygon (black). I essentially want to create a shapefile with just the polygons that don't intersect with the black polygon. I am using ArcGIS 10.3.

[image]

Comment: I believe you're looking for [Erase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/erase.htm), though using Union and selecting out the not-NULL black features is also possible (if you don't have an Advanced license).  Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and be sure to always specify the exact version of software in all questions.

Comment: Do you want to disregard the entire polygon if it intersects PR, or just the intersecting part?

Comment: I want to disregard the entire polygon. I have tried looking into the Erase tool and other common tools with Intersect, but I'm not trying to clip out a certain geometric shape. I just want to remove the spatially overlapping red polygons. I am fairly new to ArcGIS though.

Comment: @user91411 Comments are intended for potential answerers to request additional information or clarification.  Your response to these requests should be as an [edit] to your question, not as a further comment.  Please update your question with your additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the overlapping polygons with a Select by Location then Delete.

First use Select by Location, either with the [Select Layer by Location tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) or from the [Selection menu](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) in ArcMap.  Select features in your red polygon layer that intersect features in your black polygon layer.

Then Delete - either with the [Delete Features tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-features.htm) or Start Editing, and delete selected records.